# Scrolling table. Problems with shadow and `tr` border radius

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a task to make this table:
[image: table]

I have 2 problems:

1. `box-shadow` is not visible at the edges due to `overflow: auto`
   [image: 1 problem]
2. when i scrolling table, `border radius` disappears and I don't know how to save it.
   [image: 2 problem]

I am trying to do this with `display: grid`, but didn't achieve any result.

Here is my code now:

```css
body {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: #edeff5;
}
table {
 overflow-x: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 border-collapse: separate;
 border-spacing: 0 0.25rem;
 overflow-x: auto;
 width: 50rem;
 position: relative;
}
 thead,
 tbody {
   min-width: 100%;
 }
 tr {
   box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(77, 92, 127, 0.16);
   border-radius: 10px;
 }
 th:first-child,
 td:first-child {
   border-top-left-radius: 10px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 }
 th:last-child,
 td:last-child {
   border-top-right-radius: 10px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
 }
 th,
 td {
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
  color: #526092;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-align: start;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Пользователи</th>
        <th>Ролевая модель</th>
        <th>Вложения</th>
        <th>Новости</th>
        <th>Настройки почтовых уведомлений</th>
        <th>Настройки внутренних уведомлений</th>
        <th>Настройки прав</th>
        <th>Опросы</th>
        <th>Пользователи</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>user</td>
        <td>first role 999999999999 </td>
        <td>attachments</td>
        <td>news</td>
        <td>emailNotificationSettings</td>
        <td>eventNotificationSettings</td>
        <td>permissions</td>
        <td>polls</td>
        <td>user</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>user</td>
        <td>second role 999999999999 </td>
        <td>attachments</td>
        <td>news</td>
        <td>emailNotificationSettings</td>
        <td>eventNotificationSettings</td>
        <td>permissions</td>
        <td>polls</td>
        <td>user</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

[my codepen](https://codepen.io/svobodinang/pen/mdRbOLL)

Comment: Your Page is not responsive, table is perfect

Comment: What do you mean?